# Referencing the row below the current one in OpenOffice / LibreOffice Calc

Tags: reference, openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

In OpenOffice Calc / LibreOffice Calc, I need to find out if a cell in the row below the current cell is empty.  To do this, I use the `ISBLANK()` function.

For example,
`ISBLANK(B5)`

That works well, but I need the function to be generic to always look at the row below the current row.  For example in row 4, I need to be looking at cell B5, and in row 5, I need to be looking at cell B6.

In *pseudo-code*, this is: `ISBLANK(B[row below the current one])`

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I can't just extend the formula to autofill the correct rows.

Can this be done in OpenOffice or LibreOffice?  If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

```
=ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW() + 1,COLUMN())))
```

- ROW() + 1 gives the row number below the current row.
- COLUMN() gives the current column.
- ADDRESS() followed by INDIRECT() gets the actual cell of that row and column.

Or this, which is closer to your pseudocode:

```
=ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B" & ROW()+1))
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be a semicolon instead of a comma in the first formula? (It doesn't work for me with a comma.)

Comment: It depends on the version and locale.  I have LO 5.1.0.3 and it uses commas.